# Orthographic projection in Python Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to plot a GeoTIFF in Python using Basemap. I can do so correctly with `cyl` projection like this:

```
m = Basemap(projection='cyl',
            llcrnrlat=LL[1], urcrnrlat=UR[1],
            llcrnrlon=LL[0], urcrnrlon=UR[0])
```

But if I try to do so in the `ortho` projection, it does not work. I'm using this function call:

```
m = Basemap(projection='ortho',
            lon_0 = origin[0],
            lat_0 = origin[1],
            llcrnrlat=LL[1], urcrnrlat=UR[1],
            llcrnrlon=LL[0], urcrnrlon=UR[0])
```

Basemap / matplotlib crashes with the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Basemap' object has no attribute '_height'
```

If I remove the llcrnX arguments, the `ortho` projection works, but I see the whole globe. I guess this is OK, if I can then somehow plot my image using the corner coordinate. Basemap documentation states that the corners may be specified.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I just got this error.

Comment: Doc error - you can't use lat/lon, you have to use llcrnrx, llcrnry, etc.

Comment: This is how it works for me [The parameters are for COMS-1 sattelite]: 
map = Basemap(projection='ortho', resolution='l', lat_0=36.0, lon_0=130.0,                  llcrnrx=-1393134.5247400326, llcrnry=-1494753.6065000296, urcrnrx=1393134.1277100428, urcrnry=1350584.3149082884)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a document error - you can't use lat/lon, you have to use llcrnrx, llcrnry, etc. –